# Replace multiple clicked images with new ones using modal

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog

It's been a while since I used JS and I'm getting problems creating this multiple modal-img.

I'm following [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp) guide.

The modal script is working as it should. If I click on the snow image it opens the modal with a different image (fire), but what I really need is to be able to click on different images, 10 to be exact, and open the modal with a new image different from the first one I selected.

For instance, if I click on image1 > image1.1 opens. If I click on image2 > image2.2 opens, and so on.

Any clue about how to solve this?

Someone said I should use a ForEach method, and edit the function img.onclick = function(){...}
but I already tried and have no idea about where or how should I do it.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
  let default_image = this.src;
  modal.style.display = "block";
  this.src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/36/Large_bonfire.jpg';
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  this.src = default_image;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {  
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
  to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {transform:scale(0)} 
  to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="myImg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/12/CargoNet_Di_12_Euro_4000_L%C3%B8nsdal_-_Bolna.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dict specifying the img you want to load based on which one was clicked.

Then you can select all your imgs with a common class and map through then to create the open modal function.

In each function you pass the dict value with the src you want to load.

In this example I used the title attribute to pass the new src. I also gave your `img` tags the class `myImg` to map then.

```js
modalImgs = {'catImg':'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/0c/1c/a1/0c1ca1955e2b0c5469ba17da2b1b9b96.jpg', 'dogImg': 'https://filmdaily.co/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/dog-videos-lede-1300x868.jpg'}

var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName("myImg");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

Object.keys(imgs).map(function(objectKey) {
  var img = imgs[objectKey];

  img.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = modalImgs[this.id]
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
  }
})


// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {  
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
  to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {transform:scale(0)} 
  to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="myImg" id="catImg" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/4b/6f/ec/4b6fec352ad65acf6c1265201432dfa1.jpg" alt="Cat" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">
<img class="myImg" id="dogImg" src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/976/cpsprodpb/16B90/production/_107427039_gettyimages-636475496.jpg" alt="Dog" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Arthur! Thank you for your answer! Mhhh, the thing is that I'm already using the alt info to add text to the images. Is there any other way to pass the new src?

Comment: Of course, you could pass the img a title, or also use index in your map if you asssure the dict will follow the same index. I'll change my answer to use title instead

Comment: You could also use the img id or any other attribute you cans pass for the tag and read in your function.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please edit your answer? I'm not really sure how to do it and I'm really struggling right now, I would like to understand how to do it with the img id!

Comment: Done, using id instead